# Be able to find the NuGget package to install from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package, microsoft-documentation

I'm trying to build a console project (.NetCore 3.1) to run the [matrix multiplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.matrix.multiply?view=netcore-3.1) example.

The issue is the following with VS2109

- using System.Windows.Media; (VS2019 suggest me to remove the ".Media")

Just by looking at the Microsoft documentation on the web, can you explain how can I find the package to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, scroll down to the bottom of the page, to "Applies to". You can see that it's already built into .NET 3.0+ and .NET Core 3.0+:

> [image: Applies to]

Fine, so we don't need to install a NuGet package to use it on .NET Framework and .NET Core. So what DLL is it in?

Take a look at the top of the page:

> [image: Namespace and Assembly]

We can see that it's in `WindowsBase.dll`.

Provided that you're using .NET Framework or .NET Core 3.0+, you can add a reference to `WindowsBase`:

[image: Reference Manager]

Comment: ok, need additional help to reference properly the right dll. Using the Reference Manager (VS2019) I was not able to find "WindowsBase.dll" using the search in "COM". Before to Browse, I did use "windows explorer" and found dozens of “WindowsBase.dll” in my computer using windows explorer. Which one should I select to make sure that when Microsoft perform update on my computer that “dll” will be updated if there is and update to perform?

Comment: Look in "Assemblies" for "WindowsBase" (no ".dll"). I've edited my answer.

Comment: ok "Assemblies" is not an option in my Reference Manager. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.2.       Additional info -  In my console project the Dependencies refer to Frameworks/Microsoft.NetCore.app.

Comment: What are you targetting? .NET Core 3.0? In your csproj, what's your `<TargetFramework>`?

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Comment: Ah, confusingly, it looks like it's only available in .NET Core as part of a WPF application. (I don't know of an easy way to find out that - I had to go googling). Although there is a hint [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks, I will do a WPF project instead.